# Set default text size/color for text boxes in Master Slide PowerPoint 2013

Tags: textbox, powerpoint

I'm working with a PowerPoint document which annoyingly sets all newly inserted text boxes' color to Red and uses Century Gothic. I believe this is due to the Master Slide being used by the document.

I would like to remove this automatic setting from text boxes in the Master Slide but I cannot figure out how?

I have gone into the Master Slide view and found that there are no text physical text boxes, there are however "Text Placeholders" but no text boxes. I find it strange and wonder:

**how are these newly inserted text boxes contain pre-set font type and color?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't trying to do this in code, StackOverflow isn't really the right place for the question; you want SuperUser for "How do I ..." questions that don't involve code.

But what you want to do is select a text box that's formatted the way you want default text to be, then right click it and choose Set As Default Text Box.  You won't get that option if you've clicked WITHIN the text box and have an insertion cursor; in that case press ESC, then rightclick.

If you're trying to do this in code, select a text box formatted to taste then do something like this:

```
Sub SetMeAsDefault()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    With oSh
        .SetShapesDefaultProperties
    End With
End Sub
```

The shape and text box defaults are independent of master formatting, which controls only the formatting of placeholders and text within placeholders.  Text/shapes inserted via the Insert ribbon/menu follow the defaults set for the presentation as I've described above.  Each presentation (and template) can have its own set of defaults.

Comment: Your right, I wasn't looking for code but I will use it as a last resort....Thanks!

Comment: No need ... the code just does the same thing as the manual process I described.  Either/Or but no need for both.